# HighCharts: Remove GridLine Overhang (Angular/TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts

I've tried a dozen different solutions, but there always seems to be overhang of the gridlines when they start/end directly on the tick. I'm looking for a solution to either remove this overhang, or slightly shift the start/end points so that they appear on the line, but don't trigger this overhang to pop up. Working in an Angular/TypeScript environment.

GridLine overhang:
[image]

Current graph settings:

```
chart: {
    type: 'spline'
},
title: null,
xAxis: [{
        categories: [
          'Open 11am', '12', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10pm close'
        ],
  gridLineWidth: 1,
  labels: {
    enabled: true
  },
  tickWidth: 0,
  tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
  startOnTick: true
}],
yAxis: [{
    title: null,
    labels: {
      x: 0,
      y: -2
    },
    tickLength: 0,
    tickWidth: 0
}],
series: [{
  name: null,
  data: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  marker: {
    fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
    lineWidth: 2,
    lineColor: null
  }
}],
  credits: {
      enabled: false
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  }
```

How can I prevent this overhang for showing up while having tick marks on the start and end categories?

I've tried just about every option I've come across, but I'll admit I'm still fairly new to HighCharts API. Thanks for responses in advance.

*edit:*

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bz5vk5ec/) to provide the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your `xAxis` as

```
//startOnTick: true,   
min: .5,
max: 10.5,
```

[updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bz5vk5ec/1/)

min as .5 and max 10.5 is fixed values and it removes the spaces and also remove `startOnTick: true` from the code as it forces to start from tick.
But at same time it modify with Ellipsis ,so comment `min` if ellipsis is undesired

Comment: you can also use rotate labels